# R: data.table inside GA optimization throws error

Tags: r, data.table, genetic-algorithm, doparallel

I am trying to run a GA in parallel with the packages GA and data.table.
In short, I am optimizing a high-dimensional (100k variables), non-linear objective function. For now, I am looking into a simple GA that could run in parallel. Unfortunately, when I run R's package GA in parallel with data.table I get a weird error, which hints that data.table isn't correctly instantiated.

Here a MWE, and the resulting error.

```
library(GA)
library(data.table)

sampler <- function(x){
  y <- data.table(x)
  y$x <- y$x+1 # works
  y[,x:=x+1] # does not work
  
  return(-(y$x)^2)
}

library(doParallel)

cl <- makeCluster(4) # set the number of processor cores
registerDoParallel(cl)
clusterEvalQ(cl, library("data.table"))


GA2 = ga(type = "real-valued", 
         fitness = sampler,
         lower = 0, upper = 10000,
         suggestions = 1.5,
         popSize = 100, maxiter = 10, monitor = TRUE,
         seed = 12345, parallel = cl)

stopCluster(cl)
```

> Error in { :    task 1 failed - "Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE.
> Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in
> particular ways. See help(":=")."

The code runs fine when ga is run non-parallel (remove parallel = cl). I checked whether the library data.table is loaded in the nodes, and it seems so (clusterEvalQ). I tried adding the libpath to the nodes as well; does not change the outcome...
Any suggestions would help!
Thanks!

---

**EDIT**:

As suggested by @jangorecki, I modified the code to:

```
  set(y, j="x", value=x+1)
  set(y, j="p", value=x+2)
```

This works fine now, BUT if I try to aggregate in a data.table manner:

```
  newdt <- setDT(y)[,sum(x),.(p)]
```

It won't work again, even though I am setting setDT(y). It seems as if the setDT does not have any effect. Any suggestions?

Comment: can you give some description of the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I updated my description a bit. I hope that helps.

Comment: Hi @Puki Luki. The library `data.table` already runs in parallel by default. So, I guess there may be some kind of conflict between `doParallel` and `data.table`. In your case, it may be appropriate to set the number of threads to 1 with the code `setDTthreads(1)` before running your chunk of code.

Comment: *That* error can sometimes mean that `data.table`-operations (specifically assignment with `:=`, plus others) are happening in a package/namespace that has not declared that it is `data.table`-aware. This is often remedied by adding `.datatable.aware=TRUE` (ref: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-importing.html) into the package namespace; your question doesn't sound like you are creating a package, but perhaps if you device that variable inside of whatever calls `GA` functions, it might suffice.

Comment: Thanks. I tried both ideas: I set setDTthreads(1) and .datatable.aware=TRUE inside the function "sampler", but it didn't help. Still getting the same error. Still, I think it is an issue related to the parallelization not being data.table aware.

Comment: Or DT has been serialized, which invalidates self reference, you may need setDT in each thread

Comment: Thanks! How would I do that specifically?

Comment: what if you change `setDT` into `as.data.table`?